# SpringBoot @Cachable Redis delete by partial key

Tags: java, caching, redis, spring-cache

My application has 3-4 @Cachable methods implemented with Redis.  All methods use a key with 2-3 fields, but all of them have one field in common: submFileId.  For example:

```
@Cachable
public Contract getContract (Long submFileId, Long contractId) { ...

@Cachable
public Member getMember (Long submFileId, Long memberId) { ...
```

When processing for a specific submFileId is complete, I would like to evict all the cached data for a specific submFileId, Contract and Member.  At that point in time I may not know all the contractrId and memberId values that were used as cache keys.

Suggestions? Is there a way to setup a secondary non-unique key just by submFileId so I can delete on that value alone? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a too narrowed use case to be handled by an annotation. Inject the `Cache` in your own code and do whatever you like. You'll still benefit from the abstraction even though you access it programmatically.

Comment: Going to handl it using the RedisTemplate directly